# GraphicsPath.AddPolygon not rendering properly

Tags: c#, winforms

Basically I have a form and am trying to "dim" areas of it to draw focus to a certain part of the form. To do this I'm using a Form with no border and 50% opacity, aligned with the actual form. The area I am trying to mask is the dark gray area, roughly, as pictured:

[image]

To get the "U"-shaped form, I'm using a `GraphicsPath` with `AddPolygon`, calculating the points of each vertex:

```
var p = new GraphicsPath();
var origin = new Point(Top, Left);
var maxExtentPt = new Point(origin.X + Width, origin.Y + Height);
Point[] points = {
    origin, 
    new Point(origin.X + leftPanel.Width, origin.Y),
    new Point(origin.X + leftPanel.Width, maxExtentPt.Y - bottomPanel.Height),
    new Point(maxExtentPt.X - rightPanel.Width, maxExtentPt.Y- bottomPanel.Height),
    new Point(maxExtentPt.X - rightPanel.Width, origin.Y),
    new Point(maxExtentPt.X, origin.Y),
    maxExtentPt,
    new Point(origin.X, maxExtentPt.Y),
    origin
};
p.AddPolygon(points);
overlayForm.Region = new Region(p);
overlayForm.Location = PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

The three panels in the code are what I am masking, so I am using their dimensions to calculate the points. Instead of getting my expected result, the mask looks like this, with its size changing as I resize the main form (I recalculate the region on Move and Resize):

[image]

Is there some limitation of `GraphicsPath.AddPolygon` that I'm not aware of? I double-checked (quadruple-checked, really) the results of my calculations, including taking the coordinates for each point and plugging them into Ipe to see if the shape was actually correct... It was. But not in my program!

*Edit: Here are the values of each point, when I hit a breakpoint at `p.AddPolygon(points);` I'm starting in the upper left-hand corner and going around clockwise:*

[image]

Comment: What are `Top` and `Left`?  Wouldn't they be the top and left of your borderless form in screen coordinates?

Comment: @adv12 Sorry, this code is in my "real" form, so `Top`, `Left`, `Width`, and `Height` are all relative to that.

Comment: sorry--if I had read more closely I could have figured that out myself.  In any case, from your screenshot of the point values, it looks like Top and Left must both be 0.

Comment: Correct, see my edit that shows the coordinates of each point. I could have simplified my assignments to `origin` and `maxExtentPt`, but in the end they are the correct values. I've also tried calculating with my form's `PointToScreen` to get exact locations and then just not setting the mask form's location at all, but that gave the same results and just made the code even harder to read.

Comment: It doesn't seem to hurt anything right now since `Top` and `Left` are 0, but I think you really want to define the polygon in `overlayForm`'s coordinates, where `origin` would be (by definition) (0,0) and `maxExtentPoint` would be (Width, Height).

Comment: @adv12 That was actually one of my problems. The `overlayForm`'s size was still the default, so the rest of my region was getting lopped off outside of those bound. Setting the size of the overlay to the size of my form showed the whole region, but was offset. TaW's answer helped with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your points are wrong after all.

Everything ought to be in the coordinates of the `ClientRectangle`, so

`Origin` should not be  `new Point(Top, Left)` which is the `Location` of the `Form`. It should be `Point.Empty` or `(0,0)`. Or you could use the `leftPanel.Location`.

And

```
maxExtentPt = new Point(origin.X + Width, origin.Y + Height);
```

should read:

```
var maxExtentPt = new Point(origin.X + ClientSize.Width, origin.Y + ClientSize.Height);
```

(The difference is the size of border+title..)

Let me know if that works better!

Comment: This along with adv12's comment did the trick, although to get the overlay to line up properly I used `var origin = new Point(SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width, SystemInformation.CaptionHeight);`, and I still have to tweak some of the other calculations to get it to fit properly, but the general idea is definitely there now!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try doing it this way, basing everything off the Panels:

```
        Form overlayForm = new Form();
        overlayForm.Opacity = .5;
        overlayForm.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        overlayForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        overlayForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

        var p = new GraphicsPath();
        var origin = new Point(0, 0);
        var maxExtentPt = new Point(this.Width, this.Height);
        Point[] points = {
            origin, 
            new Point(leftPanel.Right, origin.Y),
            new Point(leftPanel.Right, bottomPanel.Top),
            new Point(rightPanel.Left, bottomPanel.Top),
            new Point(rightPanel.Left, origin.Y),
            new Point(rightPanel.Right, origin.Y),
            maxExtentPt,
            new Point(origin.X, maxExtentPt.Y),
            origin
        };
        p.AddPolygon(points);
        overlayForm.Region = new Region(p);
        overlayForm.Location = this.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));

        overlayForm.Show();
```